# automatically calculating the average and st dev for multiples data frames and excluing the first column in each

Tags: r, dataframe, automation, apply, spectra

I am essentially brand new to R but need to produce some plots for my thesis.

I am working with hyperspectral data for which I have exported csvs containing groups of scans. I have taken hundreds of readings and even when spectra are grouped this produces many separate csv files.

In each csv the x-axis is in the first column and each following column contains intensities for independent spectra. the number of columns varies based on how many scans were taken in that group.

I am trying to create new columns in each dataframe which correspond to the average and st dev.

I would also like to create another dataframe which pulls the new mean and st dev columns out and places them into a new dataframe.

Comment: Could you please post a reproducible example of your data please? Could you also you also provide the code you have used to try and solve your problem please? This will help with trying to help you out with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example it's impossible to test the code below but I would do something along its lines.

```
old_dir <- setwd("path/to/dir")
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv")
df_list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)

df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(DF){
  DF[["Mean"]] <- rowMeans(DF[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
  DF[["StdErr"]] <- apply(DF[-1], 1, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
  DF
})

new_list <- lapply(df_list, function(DF){
  data.frame(Mean = DF[["Mean"]], StdErr = DF[["StdErr"]])
})

setwd(old_dir)
```

Note that `new_list` is an object of class `"list"`. You ask for a new `data.frame` with the means and sd's. If the original files do not have the same number of columns and rows, that is not possible.

Comment: Hi Rui, Sorry I did not provide a block of code but it seems you've nearly solved my problem anyway. 

I ran your provided code and it worked swimmingly. 

I should have said that I wanted the code to be placed into a new column which is appended to the spreadsheets from whence they were calculated. Now I am wracking my brain trying to solve that issue.

Comment: @AlexanderSousa Isn't the `DF`'s in the last `df_list` what you need?

Comment: Sorry, Rui, I am not sure what you mean. This is all quite advanced from my perspective.

Comment: hmmm. I think I see what you mean. I should use the line that reads 
>df_list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
I have to assign the newly generated columns to the csvs. catalogued in that list. 

trouble is I have no idea how to do that!

Comment: @AlexanderSousa So you are saying that you want to write back the dataframes with the newly created columns? I had understood the question differently, that you were just asking about *how* to create the columns.